# Modular automation testing service/framework for web app

Tags: selenium, ui-automation, ghostscript, browser-automation

I have been looking into selenium and a hosted service ghostscript for behavioral driven testing framework for our complex webapp.

I want to break this task into several small pieces of test suits which checks certain smaller feature independently. Then I want to create a bigger flow using all these smaller units. This will give me few advantages

1. I can create different flow reusing smaller units. This will also help me verifying smaller units with different entry/exit points.
2. If there is any change in some part of app, I do not have to change it in every flow its being used.
3. All the flow can be visualized easily.

Are there any tools to achieve this and make this task easy without writing everything from beginning, So that I can focus more on create smaller test units and creating flow rather than investing and setting up such infra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cucumber here.
In one of my project we had many individuals modules developed, which were later reused in multiple solutions (combination of multiple modules as per requirments).
So we achieved it with BDD framework using Cucumber to develop automation scripts for each individual’s modules and reused the same script written for individual solutions which have that module.

Comment: Thanks! cucumber can be used for automation testing for web based app too? I have used it for mobile apps automation testing. How does it work with web apps

Comment: Yes, it can be used, In fact we are still using the same BDD approach with cucumber and java for automation our website.
And everyone is liking it, as it is filling the gap between business and technical person in team.

Comment: Thanks! That is good info. I am going to explore it as well. Is there any article about how to organize test cases so that different small modules can be combined to make bigger flow.

Comment: You can follow these two links:
http://toolsqa.com/cucumber/cucumber-tutorial/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cucumber/index.htm

Comment: Once you have written feature(Lets say: Feature_module1) file for one module, you can reuse the same steps and scenarios in the Feature_module1 file into your new feature (Lets say: Feature_solution1) file, which is combination of multiple scenarios from different  Feature_module.

Comment: Thanks for the info. it makes sense. Is there any guide to integrate it with jenkins or any CI tool?